# Calculating limit including greatest integer function

Tags: limits, solution-verification

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \left((1.5)^n +[(1+0.0001)^{10000}]^n\right)^{1/n}$   where [] means greatest integer function

I simplified the expression  using binomial expansion as

$ \left((1.5)^n+ 2^n\right)^{1/n}$

$L = \left((1.5)^n+ 2^n\right)^{1/n}$

$\log (L)= \frac{1}{n} \log(1.5)^n +\frac{1}{n} \log(2)^n  $

$\log(L) =\log(3)$

This gives limit as $3$ but answer stated is e. I'm not able to find a flaw here

Comment: $[(1+0.0001)^{10000}] \approx e$  not $2$

Comment: $(a^n+b^n)^{1/n} \to \max(a,b)$

Comment: $\log((a^n+b^n)^{1/n})= \frac1n \log(a^n+b^n) \not = \frac1n \log(a)^n+\frac1n \log(b)^n$

Comment: @AdamRubinson At the moment I am just making assertions.  I have no problem with you or anybody else using these if they wish

Comment: @AdamRubinson wanna write the answer?

Comment: @Henry got my errors but what's the correct way of doing this

Comment: @Henry $[(1+0.0001)^{10000}] = 2$, if we assume the usual notation of $[ \cdot ]$ to mean floor function.

Comment: If you expand the expression in binomial series, $\sum_{k=0}^{10000}\binom{10000}{k} (\frac{1}{10000})^k$, then the first two terms already sum to $2$, so the whole expression can't be $2$

Comment: @Kaind if that is what is meant.  Not quite consistent with "answer stated is $e$"

Comment: That is true. Though the question does mention "greatest integer". I believe OP could have made a typo and actually meant $[ (1+0.0001)^{10000n} ]$,

Comment: @Kaind no it's not a typo

Comment: @AdamRubinson greatest integer function

Comment: Ok, that's the same as the floor function I believe. I've edited my answer now. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

One mistake is the following:

$L = \left(1.5^n+ 2^n\right)^{1/n}\implies\log (L)= \frac{1}{n} \left(\log(1.5)^n + \log(2)^n\right). $

Correct is:

$L = \left((1.5)^n+ 2^n\right)^{1/n}\implies\log (L)= \frac{1}{n} \log\left(1.5^n + 2^n\right). $

Next,

$(1+0.0001)^{10000}\approx e = 2.718\ldots\ .\ $ Therefore, $\lfloor{(1+0.0001)^{10000}\rfloor} = 2.$

Furthermore for $a>0,\ b>0$,

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(a^n +b^n\right)^{1/n} = \max\{a,b\}.$$

Since $2 = \lfloor{(1+0.0001)^{10000}\rfloor} > 1.5,\ $ we therefore have:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \left((1.5)^n +\lfloor(1+0.0001)^{10000}\rfloor^n\right)^{1/n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left((1.5)^n +2^n\right)^{1/n} = 2.$$

Answer (score 0):

$
\begin{align*}
L &= (1.5^n + 2^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \\
&= 2 (1 + 0.75^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \\
\Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} L &= 2
\end{align*}
 $

Comment: That's true, I originally thought it was of the form $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$, which is why I took $\log$, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to see is that $s_{}=(1+\frac{1}{10^3})^{10^3}$ is greater than $\frac{3}{2}$ by expanding in Binomial series, as I wrote in the comments, as the first two terms sum to $2$, so that $\frac{3}{2s}<1$. Then, pull it out of the brackets:
$$
s(1+(\frac{3}{2s})^{n})^n = s e^{n \log (1+(\frac{3}{2s})^n)} \approx s e^{n (\frac{3}{2s})^n} \to_n s
$$
You can add more terms from Maclaurin series expansion to get upper and lower bounds, but $n \alpha^n$ converges to $0$ regardless for $|\alpha|<1$, so the results follows.